# Local ci pipeline with gitlab using docker

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I installed gitlab via docker locally successfully on port 9800 in an own network "cinet". Now I would like to set up a ci pipeline. For that I first have to install a gitlab-runner and then to register it. The registration fails, however.

Starting gitlab like so

```
$ docker run --name=gitlab --volume="/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab" --volume="/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab" --volume="/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab" -p 9800:80 -p 22:22 -p 443:443 --network=cinet --restart=no --detach=true gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

The gui is ready under `http://localhost:9800`. I created a java maven projekts with a .gitlab-ci.yml and pushed it into my local gitlab instance successfully. The ci pipeline is stuck as expected since there is no runner yet intalled/registered.

[Installing the runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html)

```
$ docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --network=cinet gitlab/gitlab-runner
```

[Registering the runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html#docker). I first tried a shared runner and obtained the token from the ci gui.

```
$ docker run --rm -t -i -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner --network=cinet gitlab/gitlab-runner register
```

The I am prompted for host, token, description and tags. Tags I left empty. For host I tried:

1. `http://localhost:9800/` - That results in the following error:

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=Lt7NVbJ_ status=couldn't execute POST against http://localhost:9800/api/v4/runners: Post http://localhost:9800/api/v4/runners: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9800: connect: connection refused
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

2. `http://172.19.0.2:9800/` - That results in the following error:

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=Lt7NVbJ_ status=couldn't execute POST against http://172.19.0.2:9800/api/v4/runners: Post http://172.19.0.2:9800/api/v4/runners: dial tcp 172.19.0.2:9800: connect: connection refused
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

Why is that failing? What do I need to do to make that run?

Comment: I avoided some issued with the help of https://serverfault.com/questions/814164/connect-gitlab-and-gitlab-runner-both-in-docker but running into new connectivity problems when my pipeline starts. My gitlab is trying to download image maven:latest but fails with:  fatal: unable to access 'http://82a283f455d8/root/pronto.git/': Could not resolve host: 82a283f455d8
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:02
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1